# How do I display todays date in Node.js Jade?

Tags: node.js, date, pug

I am new to Node.js and Jade and I have tried to use `#{Date.now()}` and it's giving me numbers. How do I display the date in `mm/dd/yy` format?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

First, add moment to your express application locals

```
express = require('express');
...
app = express();
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

Then you can use moment within a jade template like this:

```
p #{moment(Date.now()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}
```

Moment takes `Date.now()` by default, so yo can also write:

```
p #{moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')}
```

---

Sources:

- [Making use of utility libraries in server-side Jade templates](https://coderwall.com/p/egh53a)
- [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: MomentJs is a really big library. It's fantastic for comparisons and working with dates, but if you just want to display todays date you really don't need to include a library and can take a look at any of the pure JS answers..

Comment: @MattJHoughton Yeah moment is quite big.. have a look at https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns

Answer (score 9):

This is old, but I do the following:

```
return (new Date()).toLocaleDateString()
```

Returns a date 'mm/dd/yyyy' format, in no additional libs required.

Comment: `or (new Date()).getFullYear();` for the full year only (e.g. in the footer)

Comment: Is any options is available to change the format  'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 8):

Or you could use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to handle dates and format them accordingly to your needs

Answer (score 5):

I actually started using date-util which is 2 parts both clientside and server side.

URL https://github.com/JerrySievert/node-date-utils

**Using within a Browser**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date-utils.min.js"></script>
```

**Using with Node.js**

```
$ npm install date-utils

require('date-utils');
```

*Note: This did not work in the REPL before Node.js 0.6 due to how Node.js handles context in the REPL.*

**Static Methods**

```
Date.today(); // today, 00:00:00
Date.yesterday(); // yesterday, 00:00:00    
Date.tomorrow(); // tomorrow, 00:00:00

Date.validateDay(day, year, month); // true/false whether a date is valid
Date.validateYear(year); // true/false whether a year is valid
Date.validateMonth(month); // true/false whether a month is valid
Date.validateHour(hour); // true/false whether an hour is valid
Date.validateMinute(minute); // true/false whether a minute is valid
Date.validateSecond(second); // true/false whether a second is valid
Date.validateMillisecond(millisecond); // true/false whether a millisecond is valid

Date.compare(date1, date2); // -1 if date1 is smaller than date2, 0 if equal, 1 if date2 is smaller than date1
Date.equals(date1, date2); // true/false if date1 is equal to date2

Date.getDayNumberFromName(name); // su/sun/sunday - 0, mo/mon/monday - 1, etc
Date.getMonthNumberFromName(name); // jan/january - 0, feb/february - 1, etc
Date.isLeapYear(year); // true/false whether the year is a leap year
Date.getDaysInMonth(monthNumber); // number of days in the month
```

**Instance Methods**

```
d.clone(); // returns a new copy of date object set to the same time
d.getMonthAbbr(); // abreviated month name, Jan, Feb, etc
d.getMonthName(); // fill month name, January, February, etc
d.getUTCOffset(); // returns the UTC offset
d.getOrdinalNumber(); // day number of the year, 1-366 (leap year)
d.clearTime(); // sets time to 00:00:00
d.setTimeToNow(); // sets time to current time
d.toFormat(format); // returns date formatted with:
  // YYYY - Four digit year
  // MMMM - Full month name. ie January
  // MMM  - Short month name. ie Jan
  // MM   - Zero padded month ie 01
  // M    - Month ie 1
  // DDDD - Full day or week name ie Tuesday 
  // DDD  - Abbreviated day of the week ie Tue
  // DD   - Zero padded day ie 08
  // D    - Day ie 8
  // HH24 - Hours in 24 notation ie 18
  // HH   - Padded Hours ie 06
  // H    - Hours ie 6
  // MI   - Padded Minutes
  // SS   - Padded Seconds
  // PP   - AM or PM
  // P    - am or pm
d.toYMD(separator); // returns YYYY-MM-DD by default, separator changes delimiter

d.between(date1, date2); // true/false if the date/time is between date1 and date2
d.compareTo(date); // -1 if date is smaller than this, 0 if equal, 1 if date is larger than this
d.equals(date); // true/false, true if dates are equal
d.isBefore(date); // true/false, true if this is before date passed
d.isAfter(date); // true/false, true if this is after date passed
d.getDaysBetween(date); // returns number of full days between this and passed
d.getHoursBetween(date); // returns number of hours days between this and passed
d.getMinutesBetween(date); // returns number of full minutes between this and passed
d.getSecondsBetween(date); // returns number of full seconds between this and passed

d.add({ milliseconds: 30,
        minutes: 1,
        hours: 4,
        seconds: 30,
        days: 2,
        weeks: 1,
        months: 3,
        years: 2}); // adds time to existing time

d.addMilliseconds(number); // add milliseconds to existing time
d.addSeconds(number); // add seconds to existing time
d.addMinutes(number); // add minutes to existing time
d.addHours(number); // add hours to existing time
d.addDays(number); // add days to existing time
d.addWeeks(number); // add weeks to existing time
d.addMonths(number); // add months to existing time
d.addYears(number); // add years to existing time
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the methods on the Date object to achieve what you're after. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

For example, the code below should do what you need:

```
var dateNow = new Date();
var dd = dateNow.getDate();
var monthSingleDigit = dateNow.getMonth() + 1,
    mm = monthSingleDigit < 10 ? '0' + monthSingleDigit : monthSingleDigit;
var yy = dateNow.getFullYear().toString().substr(2);

var formattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy;
```

So if you were using say jade with express and node you could do something like:

```
res.render('jadeTemplateName', { 
    dateNow: function() {
        var dateNow = new Date();
        var dd = dateNow.getDate();
        var monthSingleDigit = dateNow.getMonth() + 1,
            mm = monthSingleDigit < 10 ? '0' + monthSingleDigit : monthSingleDigit;
        var yy = dateNow.getFullYear().toString().substr(2);

        return (mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy);
    } 
})
```

and in your jade template say if you wanted to add the date to a span:

```
span Today's date is #{dateNow()}
```

Comment: I dont see how i would put all that in jade #{ }

Comment: Apologies I missed jade in the title. Answer corrected to include jade

Answer (score 0):

add the class .post-date to a tag holding the date

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('post-date');
                // get the number of selected elements

                // iterate over elements and output their HTML content
                for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
                    //console.log(list[i].innerHTML);
                    var string=list[i].innerHTML;
                    var length = 15;
                    var trimmedString = string.substring(0, length);
                    list[i].innerHTML=trimmedString ;
                }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution 
1.Create a function in pug using - syntax
2.pass the varible to the function when pug.js is binding variables to the pug template

```
    -function prettyDate(dateString){
                        -var date = new Date(dateString);
                        -var d = date.getDate();
                        -var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
                        -var m = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
                        -var y = date.getFullYear();
                        -return d+' '+m+' '+y;
                    -}
3.span.post-date #{prettyDate(val.date)};
```